# fatal error lnk1104 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl

I am using openssl ssleay.lib my project say MyProj which is also an library project.
There are many other project under this workspace which are using MyProj library.

I did the settings in MyProj library for using openssl.
Which compiles and links fine.
But when I try to compile whole workspace.
then I am getting the error

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "libeay32.lib"
al error LNK1104: cannot open file "ssleay32.lib"

How can i solve this issue ?

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: No idea, depends on a million things - hire someone to have a look on Remote Desktop

Comment: Have you checked the library directories of your linker and verified that the files are actually there?

Comment: Yes I check all dlls and lib file are at location

Comment: enable managed incremental build settings in vs worked for me.
set the value to NO

Comment: When building your whole solution(workspace) are you getting the errors when compiling `MyProj`?

Comment: MyProj compiles fine, but when i compile workspace it throws build error.